# Getting content from a phpfile every X seconds with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Is this possible? I need to get some data from another phpfile and I want it to appear every X seconds without you having to refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is known as ["polling" or "periodic refresh"](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

You can use `setInterval` (see @Luca's answer) and [jQuery's ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to communicate with the PHP file, and jQuery's DOM manipulation API to change the contents of the page. In its simplest form:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Use `setInterval` to execute something every x milliseconds.

```
setInterval(function(){

    // your code

}, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

Comment: I'm completely horrible with javascript and jquery, How do I get the content from a PHP file?